# Do CTEs use any space in tempdb?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, tempdb

Do CTEs use any space in tempdb or does it use memory exclusively?

I've tagged the question with both mssql 2005 and 2008 as I use both.

Comment: Queries are certainly noted in <http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966545.aspx#EEAA>. See the section below this on "Space required by queries" also.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll try not to copy/paste MSDN

It doesn't matter.

A CTE is independent of query execution: it is only a language construct. Think of it as neat derived table or subquery.

This means that except for recursive CTEs (see later), **all** CTEs can be coded inline. If you use the CTE code once, it is for *readability*. If you use the CTE twice or more, then it is defensive: you don't want to make a mistake and have the derived table different each use.

Where a CTE is used twice or more, then that code will be executed twice or more. It won't be executed once and cached in tempdb.

Summary: it may or may not, just like if the code was inline.

Note: a recursve CTE is simply a derived table inside a derived table inside a derived table inside a a derived table inside a der... so same applies.

You can see this in [Tony Rogerson's article](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/05/17/non-recursive-common-table-expressions-performance-sucks-1-cte-self-join-cte-sub-query-inline-expansion.aspx). The use of tempdb would happen anyway if coded inline. He also notes that using a temp table can be better because of the "macro" expansion I explained above

FYI: the same applies to views. Just macros.

Comment: It matters if you don't realize it's using tempdb ... and then the drive with tempdb on it runs out of space while running your CTE.

Comment: Heads up, the link to that article now redirects to a NSFW website.

Answer (score 11):

> A common table expression can be thought of as a temporary result set
>   that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT,
>   UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. When the query plan for a
>   common table expression query uses a spool operator to save
>   intermediate query results, the Database Engine creates a work table
>   in tempdb to support this operation.

[**source**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345368.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345368.aspx

A common table expression can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement.

When the query plan for a common table expression query uses a spool operator to save intermediate query results, the Database Engine creates a work table in tempdb to support this operation.